# PCA on levels or returns, and standardized or not?

Tags: quant-trading-strategies, statistical-finance, pca

When you run PCA on some financial assets, let’s say stocks, do you calculate covariance on levels, standardized levels, returns or standardized returns?

I’ve seen several papers and posts that suggest to calculate covariance on the series that has been standardized (removed mean and divided by standard deviation) with the main idea being to put assets on the same scale. Otherwise, PCA can load heavily on the asset with the highest variance.

However, there are many authors that claim that in PCA, covariance should be calculated on the stationary series. Therefore, would you skip standardization and just calculate covariance on returns or would you calculate returns and then standardize these returns before calculating covariance?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with PCA?

Comment: I would like to get PCA from the group of variables (eg stocks, bonds) and then to use it in a linear regression. For example, regressing S&P 500 on few principle components and checking the residual from actual and fitted value.

Comment: OK, and what would you do that for? Technically you can do this with any transformation of the data. We still need some motivation/goal to be able to distinguish how to do that best.

Comment: The motivation for comparing the model implied value and actual value is to come up with some sort of fair value model. For example, if the reaidual is above some z-score level that would be a signal to sell. Conversely, if it is below it would be the signal to buy. Thank you.

Comment: To add to comment above. My concern is that covariance matrix from non-stationary data is not appropriate and hence, it would be better to use covariance matrix estimated on changes and/or returns. The next step would be to standardize data to make sure the inputs have similar variance. Once we have that we can proceed to PCA analysis. To sum up, first step is transformation, the second step standarization, the thrid step covariance matrix and PCA. I would appreciate your thoughts. Thanks.